# Deserialize JSON into dynamic class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to deserialize a JSON string into a type which is not know at compile time. There are several classes that it can be deserialized into. The name of the class is provided as input into the application and based on that I want to instantiate the class (already done this through reflection):

```
var type = Type.GetType(className);
var myClassInstance = (IParser)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

...and then use its type as the generic type parameter for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(myClassInstance).Name>(jsonString)` but that doesn't work.

How can I provide the class to `DeserializeObject<>()` dynamically?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217807/discussion-on-question-by-val-deserialize-json-into-dynamic-class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an generic method overload like [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) and having to resort to reflection as some comments state, you could simply use the non generic counterpart [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String, Type)`](http://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm), which just takes in a `Type` instance like you already have!

Answer (score -1):

Implementation

Initialization

```
var class1s = new Class1() {
    ID = 1, Name = "Test", Comment = "This Code is Tested!."
};
var class2s = new Class2() {
    xVal1 = 1, XVal2 = 5, xval3 = 10
};

var JSON1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(class1s);
var JSON2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(class2s);
```

Calling Functions

```
var classname1 = typeof(Class1).FullName;
var type1 = Type.GetType(classname1);

var classname2 = typeof(Class2).FullName;
var type2 = Type.GetType(classname2);

var c = LocalConverter(JSON1, type1);
var c2 = LocalConverter(JSON2, type2);
```

Class Models

```
public class Class1 {
    public int ID {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Comment {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class Class2 {
    public int xVal1 {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int XVal2 {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int xval3 {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Required Method

```
private object LocalConverter(string o, Type xtype) {
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(o, xtype);

}
```

Comment: They don't know `muClass`.